# dplyr filtering on multiple columns using "%in%"

Tags: r, statistics, dplyr

I have a dataframe (df1) with multiple columns (ID, Number, Location, Field, Weight). I also have another dataframe (df2) with more information (ID, PassRate, Number, Weight).

I am trying to use dplyr and %in% to filter out rows in df1 that have the same two values as df2.

So far I have:

```
df_sub <- subset(df1, df1$ID %in% df2$ID & df1$Weight %in% df2$Weight)
```

But this is only subsetting on the first condition...any idea why?

Comment: `df1[paste0(df1$ID,df1$Weight)%in%paste0(df2$ID,df2$Weight),]`

Comment: Use `anti_join`

Comment: Or `merge` or `inner_join` on both `ID` and `Weight`... Ignore the `&&` comment it is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question and sample code, it is unclear whether you want `df_sub` to contain the rows in `df1` which do have matches in `df2`, or the ones without matches. `dplyr::semi_join()` will return the rows with matches, `dplyr::anti_join()` will return the rows without matches.

```
df_sub <- semi_join(x=df1, y=df2, by=c("ID","Weight"))
```

or

```
df_sub <- anti_join(x=df1, y=df2, by=c("ID","Weight"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
df1[paste0(df1$ID, df1$Weight) %in% paste0(df2$ID, df2$Weight), ]
```

what you are doing is filter the `df1` by `df2` value , not find the row match

Try this sample data

```
df1 
ID  Weight
1   a
2   b


df2 
ID  Weight
1   b
2   a
```

Using your function

```
 df_sub <- subset(df1, df1$ID %in% df2$ID & df1$Weight %in% df2$Weight)


> df_sub
  ID Weight
1  2      b
2  1      a
```

Actually , it give back the Boolean like below which cause all `df1` value show up on `df2`  :

```
 True  True
 True  True
```

using mine, the result is no one match  :

```
 df1[paste0(df1$ID, df1$Weight) %in% paste0(df2$ID, df2$Weight), ]

[1] ID     Weight
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```